# Formula to pull a specific data point that changes based on month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to stack overflow so my apologies if the format of this message is incorrect.

In excel I am trying to pull the data from a specific row based on a changing month
For example
[image]

I honestly don't even know where to start on this. I was thinking a Vlookup with an if statement but I am very confused on how to approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Look into `INDEX`/`MATCH`, `HLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP`

Comment: I realize now an Hlookup formula would be able to pull the data if i have my month listed in the same format as the top row, but my next part would be how do I reference "June" to 6/1/2022 in the Hlookup?

Comment: `=DATEVALUE("1 " & B5 & " 2022")` Maybe? Or change row 1 to read: June, July, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The formula `=DATEVALUE(B5&1)` will give you the first of the month in the current year

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you need to make your date format same in both places.
better format is mmm-yy. because if you have months which exceeds current year then you will have problem. therefore always try to be specific about the date or months that always helps.

June-2022 is same is 01/06/2022 in my case, in your case 06/01/2022 because your computer date format is mm-dd-yyyy

You can use SUMPRODUCT OR INDEX AND MATCH

=SUMPRODUCT(($B$5:$H$8)*($B$2:$H$2=$B$12)*($A$5:$A$8=A13)

=INDEX($B$5:$H$8,MATCH(A13,$A$5:$A$8,0),MATCH($B$12,$B$2:$H$2,0))

[image: Example]